# Catch Content Security Policy directive violation

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

Content Security Policy directive can, among the other features, ensure a script from another domain cannot be injected.

Given I want inject a script, for example with a bookmarklet, where CSP forbids that,
how can I intercept the violation and for example print a message in the console or use `alert` ?

Unsuccessfully I tried the following

```js
+function () {
    try {
        var url = "http://another.domain/myscript.js",
            script = document.createElement('script');
        script.onload = function () {
            // whatever
        };
        script.setAttribute('src', url);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(script);
    } catch (e) {
        alert('Can\'t inject script, most likely due to Content-Security-Policy')
    }
}();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SecurityPolicyViolationEvent](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#violation-events) inretface provided since CSP2:

```
if ('SecurityPolicyViolationEvent' in window) { // Check browser support
  window.addEventListener('securitypolicyviolation', function(e) {
    console.log( e.violatedDirective, e.originalPolicy );
    });
  }
```

A [simplest example](https://csplite.com/csp/test219/) how it works.